# Android How to get the public tweets with out making user login in fabrics

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter-fabric, android-twitter

I know this question is asked already . I have read the twitter fabrics sdk. and its Auth but I am so dumb in understanding it.  So below is the key point what I want

What I want

1. I want to get all the tweets going on the basis of hash tag following is the example of what I want on mobile [Tweets on #Wwe](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23WWE&src=typd)
2. I want that my user should not have to sign in his/her twitter account. He just see the list of tweets in my app and get him self updated.

I have followed many tutorials but they are not helping me and also read how to get tweets from [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-tweets.html) and some other link .

Please tell me which auth do I need ? 
and How to do all these stuff. And good link with out twitter login please??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to initialize Fabric with the key and secret of your twitter app:

```
public void initFabric(Context context){
    if(!Fabric.isInitialized()) {       
          TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
          Fabric.with(context, new Twitter(authConfig));                 
    }else{
          Log.d(TAG, "Fabric already initialized");
    }
}
```

Just rememeber to keep your key and secret secret.

Then you can retrieve the tweets by account and hashtag in the following way:

```
public static TweetTimelineListAdapter retrieveTimeLineByHashtag(Context context, String hashtag){
    Log.d(TAG, "Loading tweets with hashtag " + hashtag);
    SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder().query(hashtag).build();
    return new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(context).setTimeline(searchTimeline).build();
}

public static TweetTimelineListAdapter retrieveTimeLineByAccount(Context context, String account){
    Log.d(TAG, "Loading tweets from user " + account);
    UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName(account).build();
    return new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(context).setTimeline(userTimeline).build();
}
```

Also take in account that the SearchTimeline only search for recent tweets that includes your search words, so you can find that no tweets are returned. However, I couldn't find a better way to get the tweets by Hashtag using Fabric.

Edit:

```
public class Prueba extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "TWITTER_PRUEBA";
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prueba);

        bindUI();
        initFabric(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = retrieveTimeLineByHashtag(this, "#Wwe");
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void bindUI(){
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.prueba);
    }

    public static void initFabric(Context context){

        Log.d(TAG, "Initializing Fabric");

        if(!Fabric.isInitialized()) {


                TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
                Fabric.with(context, new Twitter(authConfig));


        }else{
            Log.d(TAG, "Fabric already initialized");
        }
    }

    public static TweetTimelineListAdapter retrieveTimeLineByHashtag(Context context, String hashtag){
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading tweets with hashtag " + hashtag);
        SearchTimeline searchTimeline = new SearchTimeline.Builder().query(hashtag).build();
        return new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(context).setTimeline(searchTimeline).build();
    }

    public static TweetTimelineListAdapter retrieveTimeLineByAccount(Context context, String account){
        Log.d(TAG, "Loading tweets from user " + account);
        UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName(account).build();
        return new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(context).setTimeline(userTimeline).build();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I want to get the view which looks like original as in twitter

Comment: I've explained it a bit more

Comment: Edited with the whole class. As it is implemented it is working. Be sure to add correctly fabric in your app and use the key and secret of your twitter app.

Comment: this is the exactly look what I want , Wait let me try the code

Comment: but there is one confusion , can you please clear it , what do timeline mean ?
I think it would pick the wwe taged post from user time line ? 
where as I want it from all around the world

Comment: A Timeline is a group of tweets ordered chronologically. The searchTimeLine will retrieve every recent tweet that matches the text given. In that case "#Wwe", so it looks by tag finding the results worldwide. The other case, UserTimeLine, will check only the tweets by the user you pass, for example "@WWE"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102993/discussion-between-allay-khalil-and-luis-miguel-sierra).